# Having a Dollar Sign in Front of a Number in Input Field

Tags: html, reactjs

I would like to have a dollar sign appear as soon as you type a number into the input field.
The dollar sign is a character that is active like the numbers in the input field, like this video:
[image: ![https://imgur.com/eyvq87B]

Here is my code but it doesn't work:

```
const PanelBuySellStockDollars = ({ stockCurrentPrice }) => {
  const regex = /^-?\d*[.]?\d{0,2}$/; 
  const [estimateQuantity, setEstimateQuantity] = useState(0);
  const [inputDollars, setInputDollars] = useState("");

  const estimateQuantityHandler = (e) => {
    const getNumberOfDollars = e.target.value;
    let numberOfDollarsToString = getNumberOfDollars.toString();
    const indexOfDollarSign = numberOfDollarsToString.indexOf("$");

    if (indexOfDollarSign > 0) {
      numberOfDollarsToString = numberOfDollarsToString.replace("$", "");
    }
    const numberOfDollarBackToNumber = parseFloat(numberOfDollarsToString);
  
    const regexInput = regex.test(numberOfDollarBackToNumber);
    if (numberOfDollarBackToNumber === "" || regexInput) {
      setInputDollars("$" + numberOfDollarBackToNumber);
      const getEstimateQuantity =
        Math.round((numberOfDollarBackToNumber / stockCurrentPrice) * 100000) /
        100000;
      if (numberOfDollarBackToNumber > 0) {
        setEstimateQuantity(getEstimateQuantity);
      } else {
        setEstimateQuantity(0);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="amount">
          Amount
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          required
          onChange={estimateQuantityHandler}
          id="amount-dollar"
          name="amount-dollar"
          placeholder="$0.00"
          value={inputDollars}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>Est. Quantity</span>
        <span>{estimateQuantity}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PanelBuySellStockDollars;
```

Sorry if my code looks dumb. I'm still learning.
Please help. I appreciate it.

Comment: share the error log for reference

Comment: @newt there's no error. It shows only one number even though I input many numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `keyPressHandler` to achieve it like below and use `Intl.NumberFormat` to format it and display.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const currentcyFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
  style: "currency",
  currency: "USD"
});

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const keyPressHanlder = (event) => {
    const { key } = event;
    setValue((prevValue) =>
      key !== "Backspace"
        ? !Number.isNaN(parseInt(key)) || key === "," || key === "."
          ? prevValue + key
          : prevValue
        : prevValue.substring(0, prevValue.length - 1)
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        name="currency-input"
        onKeyDown={keyPressHanlder}
        placeholder={currentcyFormat.format("")}
        value={value !== "" ? currentcyFormat.format(value) : ""}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-violet-d00cn?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Tui, check this out !!

Comment: Amila! Thanks! It works and I'm trying to understand it. Is there a way to make it like this `https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCEgY.gif` which doesn't has anything in `value` at the beginning (just `placeholder`)? I appreciate your help!!

Comment: @Tui, did a bit of change, can you please check?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! It's pretty smart with your solution to be honest. I'm still trying to understand it and I'm having a hard time trying to find a way to work around the `.00`.